# Why do I have a Kernel Error in Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: python, kernel

I am a newbie to python. I am getting the below error in Kernel while opening jupyter notebook. Any ideas how I can resolve it? Installation of jupyter has been done via Anaconda3 - tried reinstalling and setting environment variables, but no luck so far. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\drag88\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tornado\web.py", line 1699, in _execute
        result = await result
      File "C:\Users\drag88\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 742, in run
        yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)  # type: ignore
      File "C:\Users\drag88\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\notebook\services\sessions\handlers.py", line 72, in post
        type=mtype))
      File "C:\Users\drag88\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 735, in run
        value = future.result()
      File "C:\Users\drag88\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 742, in run
        yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)  # type: ignore
      File "C:\Users\drag88\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\notebook\services\sessions\sessionmanager.py", line 88, in create_session
        kernel_id = yield self.start_kernel_for_session(session_id, path, name, type, kernel_name)
      File "C:\Users\drag88\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 735, in run
        value = future.result()
      File "C:\Users\drag88\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 742, in run
        yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)  # type: ignore
      File "C:\Users\drag88\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\notebook\services\sessions\sessionmanager.py", line 101, in start_kernel_for_session
        self.kernel_manager.start_kernel(path=kernel_path, kernel_name=kernel_name)
      File "C:\Users\drag88\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 735, in run
        value = future.result()
      File "C:\Users\drag88\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 209, in wrapper
        yielded = next(result)
      File "C:\Users\drag88\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\notebook\services\kernels\kernelmanager.py", line 168, in start_kernel
        super(MappingKernelManager, self).start_kernel(**kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\drag88\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\jupyter_client\multikernelmanager.py", line 110, in start_kernel
        km.start_kernel(**kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\drag88\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\jupyter_client\manager.py", line 240, in start_kernel
        self.write_connection_file()
      File "C:\Users\drag88\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\jupyter_client\connect.py", line 547, in write_connection_file
        kernel_name=self.kernel_name
      File "C:\Users\drag88\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\jupyter_client\connect.py", line 212, in write_connection_file
        with secure_write(fname) as f:
      File "C:\Users\drag88\Anaconda3\lib\contextlib.py", line 112, in __enter__
        return next(self.gen)
      File "C:\Users\drag88\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\jupyter_client\connect.py", line 100, in secure_write
        win32_restrict_file_to_user(fname)
      File "C:\Users\drag88\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\jupyter_client\connect.py", line 53, in win32_restrict_file_to_user
        import win32api
    ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you had installed jupyter when there was an issue with its dependencies on Windows. See https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues/7259 . I ran into the same error.

It should be fixed on conda now, so if you uninstall and reinstall jupyterlab from conda, it should not throw that error anymore.

Answer (score 6):

- Step 2 command:  `conda activate (location of your env folder)`
- Step 3 command:  `python -m ipykernel install --user`

Works for Windows.

Answer (score 1):

I battled to get Jupyter working on my Windows 10 office computer for a number of hours. This was after installing Anaconda3. I had versions of Python 2 and 3 installed before. I was getting 'Kernel error' and also had various errors about 'win32api' and 'tornado'

I did many things but in the end main ones that, I think, helped are listed below -

On install, Anaconda3 created a data folder here -

```
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3
```

I gave my user account access to write to this folder, I am not sure if it made a difference.

Elevated to admin, I copied two dll files as below -

```
pythoncom39.dll
pywintypes39.dll
```

From -

```
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pywin32_system32
```

To -

```
C:\windows\system32
```

At the 'Anaconda Prompt', a Windows cmd screen (which was added to my start menu) after the install, I did this -

(base) C:\>`conda env create test-env`

It created 'test-env' folder at C:\Users\{windows user name}\.conda\envs\test-env

(base) C:\>`conda activate "C:\Users\{windows user name}\.conda\envs\test-env"`

(test-env) C:\>

Once in this newly created environment, I tried various other things such as these -

```
conda install jupyter
conda install pywin32
python -m ipykernal install --user
```

Launching jupyter after loading and setting to this environment now works by using this command -

(test-env) C:\>`jupyter notebook`

When browser opens, select New>python 3 (ipykernel) from right hand menu to create new notebook.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Python installed on your pc run from cmd or powershell:

```
pip install jupyterlab
```

Then you can start it with:

```
jupyter lab
```

Answer (score 0):

The installation might have missed some steps which are fixed by post_install.
Go to yout venv's Script directory and run the command

```
python .\pywin32_postinstall.py -install
```

Make sure you are running the shell with Admin rights.

Answer (score 0):

This error is sometimes as a result of the deleted environment that was created before. For Windows users, run the following code in cmd

python -m ipykernel install –user

Answer (score 0):

Simply uninstall and install jupyter by first:
#Activate your environment in anaconda prompt (conda activate"path") and then type:-

1. conda uninstall jupyter
2. conda install jupyter